# Что правильно сделать, если я обнаружил критическую ошибку в коде в своем старом ответе?

Tags: обсуждение

Если я ее исправлю, то вопрос взлетит в топ. Не уверен, что это нужно. Но еще хуже, если кто-то найдет вопрос через Гугл и бездумно использует код. Не хочется вредить людям.

Comment: Что вас не устраивает во всплывании вопроса?

Comment: @SergeyGornostaev видимо, запугали человека некоторые старожилы.

Comment: После первого прочтения я, правда, подумал, что там настолько крутое исправление, что вопрос просто порвёт все рейтинги (взлетит в топ), но это всего лишь "поднятие на главной".

Comment: @SergeyGornostaev, просто вопрос был закрыт.

Comment: @alexolut, да, имелось в виду "поднятие на главной".

Comment: Закрытый вопрос не мешает править существующие ответы. К тому же, может быть кто-то решит переоткрыть.

Comment: Нет во всплытии ничего страшного. Даже если вопрос закрыт. Я регулярно исправляю свой старые ответы.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Однозначно исправлять, если не сделаете это сами, то сделает кто-то другой.